# Can I use Psycopog2's LoggingConnection with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am using SQLAlchemy 0.9.7 over Postgres with psyopg2 as the driver.

I have a stray transaction that isn't being closed properly, and in order to debug it, I would like to log all of the operations being sent to the database.

The [`psycopg2.extras.LoggingConnection`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#logging-cursor) looks like it provides the functionality I need, but I can't see how I might persuade SQLAlchemy to [use this feature of the dialect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2).

Is this possible via SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 3):

You could pass custom connection factory to SQLAlchemy engine:

```
    def _connection_factory(*args, **kwargs):
        connection = psycopg2.extras.LoggingConnection(*args, **kwargs)
        connection.initialize(open('sql.log', 'a'))
        return connection

    db_engine = create_engine(conn_string,
        connect_args={ "connection_factory": _connection_factory })
```

Alternatively, you could implement a custom cursor class (see `psycopg2.extras.LoggingCursor` for example), and pass it in a similar way:

```
   connect_args={ "cursor_factory": MyCursor }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a direct answer to my own question, but a workaround: similar functionality can be obtained by [turning on query logging at the SQLAlchemy layer](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/engines.html#configuring-logging), rather than the Psycopg2 layer: